# matching a string against multiple patterns in PCRE

Tags: regex, pcre

how do we match a string against multiple patters in PCRE ? I need to match this string

```
subj1 = "9112345678 put car details of the car";

patt1 = "(\\d+) ([a-z]+) ([a-z]+) (.+)";
```

some times the subject can be like this

```
subj2 = "9112345678 put car";
```

which is matching pattern

```
patt2 = "(\\d+) ([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)";
```

since the subject is dynamic and not known a prior would like to "or" these 2 patterns and want to match the subject against a composite pattern. 
some thing like 
sub matching (patt1 or patt2) 
can we do this in PCRE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make the last chunk optional:

```
(\\d+) ([a-z]+) ([a-z]+)( (.+))?
```

And if you also need to allow "9112345678 put" then add more optional groups:

```
(\\d+) ([a-z]+)( ([a-z]+)( (.+))?)?
```

If you want to maintain nice sequential references to your capture groups and if your PCRE engine really is PC, then you can use [clustering groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?%3apattern%29) in place of some of the capturing groups:

```
(\\d+) ([a-z]+)(?: ([a-z]+)(?: (.+))?)?
```

Thanks go to Kobi for kindly suggesting this variant. With this version, matching against:

```
9112345678 put car details of the car
```

will yield:

- `"9112345678"` in `$1`
- `"put"` in `$2`
- `"car"` in `$3`
- `"details of the car"` in `$4`

And that's probably easier to deal with than accounting for all the extra nesting.

Comment: Thanks mu for the reply , basically my problem in detail is the string can also be "9112345678 put" thats why i want to use multiple patterns and or them.

Comment: @Ravikumar: Then just add more optional sections as in my update. You should have included that in the question.

Comment: +1, but there's a certain disregard of the OP's capturing groups - `(\\d+) ([a-z]+)(?: ([a-z]+)(?: (.+))?)?` would probably play nicer with the OP's existing code.

Comment: @Kobi: Fair enough but in truth I find a lot of extended regex syntax a bit noisy. I'll edit that version in as an update though. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks kobi that helped a lot was exactly looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *or* operator `|`. Something like `([a-z]+)|([1-9]+)` .

Comment: Thank keith, the thing is instead of single pattern i have a group of patterns how do we or "multiple pattern groups" ?

Comment: You can (group them) | (with more) | (than one group) | (or-ed together). :-)  It's like a literal translation of your "(patt1 or patt2). That's what the or (|) operator is for.